# Update a table values from the same table based on a value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables, Students and Grades and Group, I want to update the Students who have at least one grade below 5 and change their Group.

So far i found a way just to select the students with at least one grade below 5.

```
SELECT Student.Name
FROM Student
JOIN (
    SELECT Student, Subject
    FROM Grades
    WHERE [Grade] < 5
) AS LowGrades ON Student.Id = LowGrades .Student
GROUP BY Student.Name
```

Comment: Your title says `insert` your question says `update`, you have not shown details of the tables nor explained what should be inserted... or is that updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A student has many grades and belongs to one group. If a student has at least one grade below 5, you want to change their group. So, you want to lookup a student's grades. For a lookup we use `EXISTS` or `IN`.

The update statement would look something like this:

```
update students
set group_id = 123
where exists
(
  select null
  from grades
  where grades.student_id = student.student_id
  and grades.grade < 5
);
```

or this:

```
update students
set group_id = 123
where student_id in
(
  select grades.student_id
  from grades
  where grades.grade < 5
);
```

For such simple queries I prefer `IN` over `EXISTS` (and we don't really need the qualifiers either):

```
update students
set group_id = 123
where student_id in (select student_id from grades where grade < 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the same context that your select query is in, just take out the SELECT statement and replace it with the update. (No need for the GROUP BY)

```
UPDATE Student SET group_id = 123
FROM Student
JOIN (
    SELECT Student, Subject
    FROM Grades
    WHERE [Grade] < 5
) AS LowGrades ON Student.Id = LowGrades .Student
```

You could take that a step further and CASE out a new group_id based on pre-defined grade levels, thus covering multiple instances all at once:

```
UPDATE Student SET group_id = COALESCE(LowGrades.NewGroupID, group_id)
FROM Student
JOIN (
    SELECT Student, Subject
    , CASE 
        WHEN [Grade] BETWEEN 0  AND 5 THEN 123
        WHEN [Grade] BETWEEN 6  AND 10 THEN 456
        WHEN [Grade] BETWEEN 11  AND 15 THEN 789 
        ELSE NULL --If they don't fall in the above groups, then no change
    END  as  NewGroupID
    FROM Grades
    WHERE [Grade] BETWEEN 0 AND 15 --Potentially optional condition at this point
) AS LowGrades ON Student.Id = LowGrades.Student
```

EDIT: You will maybe need to figure out how Subject works in all this. Can't tell based on the info provided, but adjust accordingly if it is in some way a factor. I see now you might get multiple results per student depending on how your Grades and Student tables are structured.